# Partition functions in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

DF:

```
ID col1 . .....coln....  Date
1                        1991-01-11 11:03:46.0
1                        1991-01-11 11:03:46.0
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0
```

I am creating a new column "identify" to find the partition of (ID, DATE) and to select the top most combination with ordering by "identify"

Expected DF:

```
ID col1 . .....coln....  Date .                    identify
1                        1991-01-11 11:03:46.0 .     1
1                        1991-01-11 11:03:46.0       1
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0 .     2
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0 .     2 
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0 .     2
```

Code Tried 1:

```
var window = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("DATE")
df = df.orderBy($"DATE").withColumn("identify", row_number().over(window))
```

My OP:

```
ID col1 . .....coln....  Date .                    identify
1                        1991-01-11 11:03:46.0 .     1
1                        1991-01-11 11:03:46.0       2
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0 .     3
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0 .     4
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0 .     5
```

Code Tried 2:

```
 var window = Window.partitionBy("ID","DATE").orderBy("DATE")
df = df.orderBy($"DATE").withColumn("identify", row_number().over(window))
```

My OP:

```
ID col1 . .....coln....  Date .                    identify
1                        1991-01-11 11:03:46.0 .     1
1                        1991-01-11 11:03:46.0       2
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0 .     1
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0 .     2
1                        1991-02-22 12:05:58.0 .     3
```

Any suggestions on how to tweak the code to get the required OP will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var window = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("DATE")
df = df.orderBy($"DATE").withColumn("identify", dense_rank().over(window))
```